# the convergence and divergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If $a_n\ge0$,$S_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent. I define the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{{S_n}^\alpha},\;\alpha\ge 0.$$

I want to know for which $\alpha$ is this series convergent and for which $\alpha$ is this series is divergent? And how to prove this?
I only know when $\alpha=1$, the series is divergent; when $\alpha=2$, the series is convergent.

Comment: The series is certainly not always divergent, even when $\alpha=0$, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ might itself be convergent. What assumptions are you making on the $a_n$? Or what question are you asking (always divergent/convergent, possibly divergent/convergent)?

Comment: Why exactly is the series divergent for $\alpha=1$? I must be missing something... under the current assumptions, since $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $S_n \to \ell>0$ (the case $a_n=0$ is trivial). Then $\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha} \sim \frac{a_n}{\ell^\alpha}$, so the series $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}$ converges by comparison...

Comment: Ah, if you change the "$\sum_n a_n$ is convergent" to  "$\sum_n a_n$ is divergent," indeed, the question changes a bit. You did that **after** accepting an answer, though?

Comment: How can you edit your question so much the answer is different, yet keep the same "accepted answer"?!

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question by mistake before. My real intention is ∑an is divergent, but I left out this condition when I first edited, then I added the condition but it was written to "convergent",so I corrected it to "divergent".But it already resulted some misunderstandings in the comment.I am sorrry for that.@ClementC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your problem, we know the following proposition:  If $a_n\ge0,\ S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{a_i}$,

(i) When $\alpha>1$, then the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}}$ is convergent.

(ii)When $\alpha\le 1$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is divergent, then the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}}$ is also divergent.

The skeleton of proof. (i) $\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_n^\alpha}\le \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}{\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}}(\alpha>1)$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}}\le a_1+\int_{a_1}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}}<\infty$.

(ii) $\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}=\frac{S_n-S_{n-1}}{S_{n-1}}\ge \int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}{\frac{dx}{x}}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=\infty$, then $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_{n-1}}}\ge \int_{a_1}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x}}=\infty$, furthermore $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_n}}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{S_n^\alpha}}(\alpha\le1)$ are divergent by principle of comparison.